# PyGame: pygame.image.load() does not show anything

Tags: python, pygame, geometry-surface, blit

I am doing an assignment with pyGame, a very simple one, we have to load an image in a window, but it does not load! And the IDLE does not show any errors..I tried relative paths to my image (room.png) also absolute paths (C:...\room.png) but nothing. Here is my code.

```
import pygame, sys      #import pygame and system library
from pygame import *    #import all pygame sublibs

pygame.init()
screen = display.set_mode((385,384))    #set screen size
display.set_caption("Blit example")
                        #this one gets the current working directory
background_file_name = "room.png"           #import bg
background_surface = pygame.image.load(background_file_name)    #use bg

while True:
        for e in pygame.event.get():
                if e.type==QUIT:        #break the loop and quit
                        pygame.quit()
                        sys.exit()
                        break


screen.fill((255,0,255))            #fill the screen with magenta
screen.blit(background_surface, (0,0))
display.update()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your indentation is messed up.

You only start drawing *after* the application has ended.
Try putting the drawing code into your main loop.

Comment: Actually, this is the code copied from the instructor's notes. It worked for him, it does not work for me (although files are in the correct place).

I have no idea about programming anyway, it's like I try to find my way in the dark.

Comment: Then understand the code, and fix the indentation of the last block. It's not hard. You just need to get the *painting* part into the *waiting* part.

Answer (score 1):

Since you said in a comment you had no idea about programming, you probably don't know that indenting is important in python. Your while loop is running continuously, waiting for an exit signal. But the display is only performed after that...

```
while True:
    for e in pygame.event.get():
            if e.type==QUIT:        #break the loop and quit
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
                    break


    screen.fill((255,0,255))            #fill the screen with magenta
    screen.blit(background_surface, (0,0))
    display.update()
```

now the display code is inside the while loop